# Заполнить массив из файла

Tags: c++

В файле находится двумерный массив целых чисел вида (пробелов между числами >= 1)

```
x_11 x_12 ... x_1m
x_21 x_22 ... x_2m
..................
x_n1 x_n2 ... x_nm
```

Необходимо заполнить одномерный массив целых `arr` и два целых числа `i, j` таким образом, чтобы `arr = { x_11, x_12, ..., x_1m, x_21, x_22, ..., x_2m, ..., x_n1, x_n2, ..., x_nm }` и `i = n, j = m`, за один цикл.

Comment: Что вы делали и что не получилось?

Comment: @free_ze не получилось за 1 цикл заполнить и посчитать, в этом вопрос и состоит

Comment: Приводите код и вам укажут на ошибки. Пока же это похоже на: "Сделайте за меня".

Comment: @free_ze тогда половину вопросов с "как сделать ___?" нужно удалять

Comment: Их иногда закрывают, да.

Comment: Откуда взялось ограничение «за один цикл»? Если это production-код, ограничение бессмысленно. Если это учебное задание, то сами его решайте.

Comment: @VladD а в чём разница с точки зрения именно реализации за 1 цикл или за 2? Я просто не могу придумать случай когда нельзя группу циклов в 1 сжать :)

Comment: @pavel: Можно, просто читаемость кода ухудшится. Хороший код должен быть понятен.

Comment: я просто не понял зачем это ограничение могли ввести даже на каком-нибудь учебном задании, думал вы подскажете)

Answer (score 2):

Можно вообще без циклов (явных) и лишних переменных:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v;
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), {}, std::back_inserter(v));
    std::copy(std::begin(v), std::end(v), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

<kbd>[Проверить результат](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/cV9IfwRnBggtozUT)</kbd>

---

Для получения кол-ва строк и столбцов можно читать построчно:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    std::vector<int> v;
    std::string s;
    int lines = 0;

    while(std::getline(std::cin, s))
    {
        std::istringstream ss{s};
        std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>{ss}, {}, std::back_inserter(v));
        ++lines;
    }

    std::copy(std::begin(v), std::end(v), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << "\nlines=" << lines << " rows=" << v.size() / lines << "\n";
}
```

<kbd>[Проверить результат](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/hWSquyREc8Jy26cs)</kbd>

А можно было бы и до посимвольного чтения опуститься. Парсить числовую строку на предмет пробелов и переводов строк. Но я не готов на это :)

Comment: а размеры `M` и `N` (ну то есть кол-во строк и кол-во символов в строке по отдельности) как узнавать отсюда?)